# Regular Expression for dollar amount in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this has been done a thousand times before but I'm having trouble with getting this right. I need to format the value of a text input for dollar amounts. No commas should be allowed. Only two decimal places should be allowed.
Examples of what should be allowed:

- 100
- 100.10
- $100
- $100.25

Below is my current incomplete regular expression. It currently allows multiple dollar signs to be included anywhere (not just at beginning), multiple decimal points to be included anywhere, and more than two decimal places which it shouldn't.

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    $(function(){

        jQuery('.dollarAmountOnly').keyup(function () {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^$0-9\.]/g, '');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="dollarAmountOnly"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I would greatly appreciate help. Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**EDIT**

Sorry, your question clearly asked for exactly two decimal places.  This is what you want:

```
var r = /^\$?[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?$/;

console.log(r.test("12.55"));  //true
console.log(r.test("$12.55"));  //true
console.log(r.test("$12"));     //true

console.log(r.test("$12."));    //false
console.log(r.test("$12.2"));    //false
console.log(r.test("$$12"));     //false
console.log(r.test("$12.555")); //false
```

---

You have to escape your dollar sign, then you want two option digits after the decimal point:

```
var r = /^\$?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]?[0-9]?$/;

console.log(r.test("12.55"));  //true
console.log(r.test("$12.55"));  //true
console.log(r.test("$12."));    //true
console.log(r.test("$12"));     //true

console.log(r.test("$$12"));     //false
console.log(r.test("$12.555")); //false
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PWzQg/4/)

Or, to allow arbitrary digits after the decimal point, you could use a Kleene closure instead of two optional digits

```
var r = /^\$?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/;

console.log(r.test("12.55"));  //true
console.log(r.test("$12.55"));  //true
console.log(r.test("$12."));    //true
console.log(r.test("$12"));     //true
console.log(r.test("$12.555")); //true

console.log(r.test("$$12"));     //false
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your regex but it still allows multiple dollar signs.

Comment: @SquidScareMe - are you sure?  Two dollar signs fail for me

Comment: @AdamRackis the asker also wants no $ required, but up to one allowed {0,1} would work yeah?

Comment: For some reason when I plug in your 1st regular expression all input is allowed. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @SquidScareMe - I put a fiddle up - check that out

Comment: Thanks, Adam, for all your help. Apparently I'm doing something wrong because it's not working in my code. I made a fiddle for mine as well: http://jsfiddle.net/76ZGw/

Comment: @SquidScareMe - your regex is doing what it's supposed to.  It's clearing the textbox as soon as it's valid.  Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/76ZGw/2/

Answer (score 11):

For those of us that want to allow for a comma, here is the regex for that:

```
/^\$?\d+(,\d{3})*\.?[0-9]?[0-9]?$/
```

I advocate allowing it and removing the commas on the backend if you don't actually want them. Anything to make it easier for the user.  [Jakob Nielson discusses cumbersome forms at point #7.](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-ten-web-design-mistakes-of-2005/)

Comment: Slight improvement, this allows for decimal places, but requires that two places exist following the period, if a period is entered: `/^\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})?$/` It's a combination of yours and another I'd been using for a while that I also found somewhere on Stack Overflow I believe.

Comment: @user2449231 this is a great one! Could you post this with the addition of allowing a comma?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend doing the validation not on `.keyup` (ie as the user types), but when the user submits the form.

Then instead of replacing invalid characters, you can just verify that the `dollarAmountOnly` textbox matches the right regex.

A regex for valid price is (this allows trailing/leading spaces):

```
/^ *\$?\d+(?:\.\d{2})? *$/g
```

So when the user presses submit, you see if the regex matches `dollarAmountOnly`, and if not then let the user know somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the requirement is to validate as the user types.

Comment: If you're interested there's a study on A List Apart that includes [when to validate when doing inline validation](http://alistapart.com/article/inline-validation-in-web-forms#section4).  To just say "don't do it on keyup" is a bit of an over-simplification. They found it best to do it on key up after a short delay.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex i used to identify various currencies in javascript:

```
 _this.currencyRegex = /^(\$|\€\£|\₪|)(?!0\.00)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$/;
```

and a good tool for debug:

https://regex101.com/r/hL2pF2/26

Answer (score 0):

In our use case, we also want to check for "k" (thousands) or "m" (millions) (case insensitive) on the end.

```
/^[$€£₪]?\d{1,3}(?:(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)?(?:\.\d{2}|\.\d{1,3}[km]|[km])?$/i
```

Reference: https://regex101.com/r/UsciDw/1

This works like so:

1. might start with currency symbol
2. has 1-3 digits (no more than 3 digits allowed if there are commas)
3. might have one of [n groups of `,###` OR n digits without comma]
4. might(?) end with one of [`.##` OR `.###[km]` OR `[km]`]

We're just handling dollars in the USA. If you're working in other regions that swap commas and dots, this gets more complicated if you want to keep the same rules on step 4.